# Why is a value copy of MainForm created when method is called or invoked cross thread?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling, com-interop, invokerequired

*Update: I think it has something to do with lazy instantiation of the window handle for MainForm - but haven't been able to work out quite how that would result in the behavior seen here.*

The application requests data via 3rd party COM interface providing a callback to process the results.  In the callback, the UI needs to be updated - but the update doesn't work as expected.  It's as if a value copy of MainForm had been created, when `MainForm.DataReady` is called or invoked directly cross thread, but UI update works as expected when executed from an event handler. Can you explain why?

*(Note: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id` is always `1` whether examined in MainForm or in ClassB.)*

**Initial Code** - call to DataReady from ClassB instance without InvokeRequred /Delegate /Invoke logic in MainForm. Application UI change works as expected, MainForm `SomeListControl.EmptyListMsg = "Not Available"` change doesn't 'stick' (as if applied to a separate copy of MainForm)

```
Module AppGlobals
  Public WithEvents A As ClassA
End Module

Partial Friend Class MyApplication
  Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object,
                                          ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    A = New ClassA()

  End Sub
End Class

Class MainForm

  private sub getData
    ToggleWait(True)
    SomeListControl.Clear()
    A.getData() 'Sets up the com object & callback
  end sub

  Public Sub DataReady()
    ToggleWait(False)
    ' Do something with the data
  End Sub

  Private Sub ToggleWait(toggle as Boolean)
    Application.UseWaitCursor = False
    if toggle then
      SomeListControl.EmptyListMsg = "Not Available"
    else
      SomeListControl.EmptyListMsg = "Please Wait"
    end if
  End Sub

End Class

Class ClassA

  public sub getData()
     Dim ComObj as New ComObject
     Call ComObj.setClient(New ClassB)
  End Sub

End Class

Class ClassB
  Implements IComObjectClient

  sub getdata_callback(results() as Object) handles IComObjectClient.getdata_callback
    ' Get the results
    MainForm.DataReady() 
  end sub

End Class
```

**Added InvokeRequred logic to DataReady, still called directly from ClassB**. InvokeRequired is never true, Application UI change works as expected, MainForm `SomeListControl.EmptyListMsg = "Not Available"` change doesn't 'stick' (as if applied to a separate copy of MainForm)

```
  Class MainForm
    Public Delegate Sub DataReadyDelegate(ByVal toggle As Boolean)
    ...
    Public Sub DataReady()
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New DataReadyDelegate()
        Else
          ToggleWait(False)
          ' Do something with the data
        End If
    End Sub
    ...
  End Class
```

**Invoked `MainForm.DataReady` directly from ClassB** Got exception: "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." until I forced the window handle creation. Then it's the same behavior as before, namely, InvokeRequired is never true, Application UI change works as expected, MainForm `SomeListControl.EmptyListMsg = "Not Available"` change doesn't 'stick' (as if applied to a separate copy of MainForm)

```
Class ClassB
  Implements IComObjectClient
  Public Delegate Sub DataReadDelegate()

  sub getdata_callback(results() as Object) handles IComObjectClient.getdata_callback
    ' Get the results 
    If Not MainForm.IsHandleCreated Then
      ' This call forces creation of the control's handle
      Dim handle As IntPtr = MainForm.Handle
    End If
    MainForm.Invoke(New DataReadyDelegate(AddressOf MainForm.DataReady))
  end sub

End Class
```

**Executed from Event Handler** Defined custom 'got data' events in ClassA and ClassB.  ClassA listens for ClassB.got_data_event and raises ClassA.got_data_event, MainForm listens for ClassA.got_data_event and handles it by calling DataReady().  This works - InvokeRequired is true, Invoke is excuted, Application UI and MainForm UI changes work as intended.

```
  Class MainForm
    Public Delegate Sub DataReadyDelegate()
    ...
    Public Sub DataReady()
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New DataReadyDelegate()
        Else
          ToggleWait(False)
          ' Do something with the data
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub _GotData_HandleEvent(ByVal resultMessage As String)
        DataReady()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ...
        ToggleWait(False)
        AddHandler A.GotData, AddressOf _GotData_HandleEvent
        ...
    End Sub
    ...
  End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrast:

```
  A.getData()
```

with:

```
  If Not MainForm.IsHandleCreated Then
```

You are using proper object-oriented programming syntax in the first statement.  A is an *object*.  The Form.IsHandleCreated property is an *instance* property, it requires an object name at the left side.  You however used a **type name**.  MainForm is not an object, it is a type in your code.

That this is possible is a very nasty VB.NET feature.  It exists to help VB6 programmers move to VB.NET coding, VB6 strongly encouraged using the form's type name.  Syntax inherited from VB1 before VB4 implemented anything resembling objects.

Now this is most certainly a convenience.  You can refer to the form object in another class by simply using the type name.  Note how you did *not* have that convenience with the A object.  You solved it by making it a global variable, storing it in a Module.  That doesn't win any prices either, but did allow you to reference A in any class.

Problem is, this convenience turns **deadly** when you start using the fake form object in another thread.  What you didn't count on is that this object has `<ThreadLocal>` scope.  In other words, when you use it in a worker thread then you get a *new* object of class MainForm.  This form object is not visible, you never called its Show() method.  Not that this would work, the thread does not pump a message loop so that form won't paint itself properly.  Another side effect you observed is that its InvokeRequired property doesn't behave.  It returns False.  Correctly so, the form was created on the work thread so you don't actually have to use BeginInvoke().  Not that this would work either, it is still the wrong object, not the one that the user is looking at.

So one Q&D workaround is to do the same thing with the form object as you did with the A object, store it in a global variable:

```
Module AppGlobals
  Public WithEvents A As ClassA
  Public MainWindow As MainForm
End Module
```

And initialize it from the class constructor:

```
Class MainForm
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        MainWindow = Me
    End Sub
'' etc..
End Class
```

Now you can refer to MainWindow in your classes.  And you get a reference to the actual instance of MainForm class that the user is looking at.  And get the proper return value from MainWindow.InvokeRequired.

This will solve your problem, but it is still ugly and error prone.  The right way looks like this:

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Shared MainWindow As MainForm

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As MainForm
        Get
            '' Return a reference to the one-and-only instance of MainForm
            If MainWindow Is Nothing Then
                '' It doesn't exist yet so create an instance 
                '' Creating one on a worker thread will never work, so complain
                If System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() <> Threading.ApartmentState.STA Then
                    Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot create a window on a worker thread")
                End If
                New MainForm()
            End If
            Return MainWindow
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosed(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs)
        '' Ensure that the one-and-only instance is now Nothing since it closed
        MyBase.OnFormClosed(e)
        MainWindow = Nothing
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        '' Creating more than once instance of this form can't work, so complain
        If MainWindow IsNot Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot create more than one instance of the main window")
        InitializeComponent()
        '' We need to keep track of this instance since the Instance property returns it
        MainWindow = Me
    End Sub

    '' etc...
End Class
```

Now you can use MainForm.Instance anywhere in your classes, like MainForm.Instance.InvokeRequired.  And you'll be reminded when you get it wrong with an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Lars.  I'm trying to create a canonical answer for this very common trap.  The OP sure helped by doing it both right and wrong.