# VB.Net duplicated tray icon

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, system-tray

I am making a VB.Net 2010 app, I have a background worker in my app that calls a web service. If the web service returns data, the background service then calls a Crystal report and then prints it out. At this point the system tray icon duplicates. At the end of the Web service run the background worker does a .Dispose() . If the Web service does not return any data, the system does not duplicate the icon.

Any help would be nice. Thanks!

Background worker's code:

```
 Private Sub bwCheckForAlarms_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwCheckForAlarms.DoWork
    Try
        Try
            'Checks for Alarms
            If Not e.Cancel Then
                CheckForAlarms(e)
            Else
                WrightRegistry("SeasionToken", "")
                bwCheckForAlarms.Dispose()
            End If

        Catch ex1 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1013, ex1.ToString)
        End Try
        Try
            'If on Checks for Announcesments
            If Not e.Cancel Then
                If ReadRegistry("PrintAnnouncements") = True Then
                    CheckForMessages(e)
                End If
            Else
                WrightRegistry("SeasionToken", "")
                bwCheckForAlarms.Dispose()
            End If

        Catch ex2 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1913, ex2.ToString)
        End Try
        Try
            'Checks for Systems Alerts. NO shut off. 
            If Not e.Cancel Then
                CheckForSystemMessages(e)
            Else
                WrightRegistry("SeasionToken", "")
                bwCheckForAlarms.Dispose()
            End If

        Catch ex3 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1953, ex3.ToString)
        End Try

    Catch ex0 As Exception
        AddEventLogError(1013, ex0.ToString)
    Finally
        bwCheckForAlarms.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Report Code.

```
 Public Function GenAlarmReportPrintOut(ByVal objAlarmNumber As String, ByVal objAlarmDateTime As String, ByVal objAlarmType As String, ByVal objAlarmAddress As String, ByVal objAlarmStatus As String, ByVal objAlarmCrossstreets As String, ByVal objStationAddress As String, ByVal objNotes As String, ByVal objDeptName As String, ByVal objProvidedby As String, ByVal objCommonName As String, ByVal objLogo As System.Drawing.Bitmap, ByVal objPDFFlag As Boolean, ByVal objAlarmDiscrition As String, ByVal objCopys As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim ds As New dsReporting
    Dim t As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("Alarms")
    Dim objRpt As New crpAlarmsPrnOutWithNaritive
    Dim objPath As String
    Dim objTimeStamp As String = Replace(DateTime.Now.ToString, "/", "_")
    Dim r As DataRow
    objTimeStamp = Replace(objTimeStamp, ":", "_")
    'Sets up the Datatable
    Try
        Try
            'check to see if their is a printer. 
            If ReadRegistry("SelectedPrinter") = "" Then
                AddEventLogWarning(1006, "No printer was selected")
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex0 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1006, ex0.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try

        Try
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmNumber", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmDateTime", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmType", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmAddress", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmCross", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmStatus", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("TurnByTurn", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("Notes", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("DeptName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("ProvidedBy", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("CommonName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmDiscrition", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("Logo", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))
            t.Columns.Add("AlarmGmap", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))
            t.Columns.Add("Units", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            t.Columns.Add("Naritive", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Catch ex1 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1005, ex1.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        'Adds Data to table
        Try

            r = t.NewRow()
            r("AlarmNumber") = objAlarmNumber
            r("AlarmDateTime") = objAlarmDateTime
            r("AlarmCross") = "Cross Street: " & objAlarmCrossstreets
            r("AlarmStatus") = "Status: " & objAlarmStatus
            r("AlarmType") = "Alarm Type: " & objAlarmType
            r("AlarmDiscrition") = "Reported Alarm: " & objAlarmDiscrition
            r("DeptName") = objDeptName
            r("ProvidedBy") = objProvidedby


            r("Notes") = "Notes: " & objNotes

            If Not objCommonName = " " Then
                r("CommonName") = "Common Name: " & objCommonName
            Else
                r("CommonName") = objCommonName
            End If



            r("Logo") = ToByteArray(objLogo)
            If LCase(objAlarmAddress) = "demo" Then
                r("AlarmAddress") = "Address: " & "xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xx xxxxx"
                r("AlarmGmap") = ToByteArray(GetGmap(GetGeoCodeFromGoogle("76 old Glenham RD Glenham, NY"), 5040, 5160, 18, False))
                r("TurnByTurn") = GetDrivingDirectionFromGoogle("901 main st fishkill, ny 12524", "76 old Glenham RD Glenham, NY")
            Else
                r("TurnByTurn") = GetDrivingDirectionFromGoogle(objStationAddress, objAlarmAddress)
                r("AlarmAddress") = "Address: " & objAlarmAddress
                r("AlarmGmap") = ToByteArray(GetGmap(GetGeoCodeFromGoogle(objAlarmAddress), 5040, 5160, 18, False))
            End If

            '***********************************
            'Just here to fill the Datatable with a null
            '****************************************************************************

            r("Naritive") = ""
            r("Units") = ""

            '****************************************************************************

            t.Rows.Add(r)
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1006, ex2.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Try

            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
            objRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = ReadRegistry("SelectedPrinter")
            objRpt.PrintToPrinter(objCopys, False, 0, 0)




        Catch ex2 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1007, ex2.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try

        Try
            'Save as a pdf for uploading later. 
            If objPDFFlag Then
                objPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData & "\" & objTimeStamp & ".pdf"
                objRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, objPath)
                frmMain.ExportedCalls.Add(objPath)
            End If
        Catch ex3 As Exception
            AddEventLogError(1008, ex3.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
    Catch ex4 As Exception
        AddEventLogError(1009, ex4.ToString)
        Return False
    Finally
        ds.Dispose()
        t.Dispose()
        objRpt.Dispose()
        objPath = Nothing
        r = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Wow! I can picture it. But, perhaps, justs perhaps, we're unable to find the fault in your code if we can't see your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a value copy of MainForm created when method is called or invoked cross thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202002/why-is-a-value-copy-of-mainform-created-when-method-is-called-or-invoked-cross-t)

Comment: Where is the code that displays notification icon?  I'm not seeing it here.

Comment: i don't have any code for that. i just use the drop in control. i do have some code for when i dobble click the icon. it hides/show my app.